# Is the Nazi dentist pretending to be a Jew in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, marathon-man

Szell is in the diamond district (trying to find out just how much money his stolen jewels are worth and it sure is a lot, perhaps hundreds of millions), in the 1970s an area where there were according to the film many Holocaust survivors -- only 30 years after World War 2, this is very plausible.

He is recognized and implies that he had fled Germany due to the nazis -- but he chooses the name Christopher Hess, a very non-Jewish name. Is he so antisemitic that he can't bring himself to even pretend to be Jewish when he is recognized by former inmates at the camp at which he worked?

I have not read the book in decades and the movie does not address this.

EDIT: I note the following simple thing I just saw in rewatching MM: Szell's first name is Christian. So he was either just not thinking or deliberately chose a name close to his own in case someone who knew him called him by his right name and he could respond automatically with the ability to deny the person knew him if pressed. I think real-life nazi war criminals/fugitives did this.

Comment: Is there any point to pretending to be Jewish? I mean, it seems unwise to pretend to be something that you might not be good at pretending to be.

Comment: He is a man with a German accent among Jews of an age where many were alive during and before WW2. If he is not Jewish, he could well be (in fact is) someone who had been a nazi. So his decision to pretend to be Jewish (if that was indeed his plan) makes some sense. He is just scouting -- eventually he hopes to move millions and millions of diamonds and can't risk being a suspected nazi.

Comment: On the other hand, all good lies have some truth in them.

Comment: You mean Szell really was Jewish -- yes, that probably is right.

Comment: I meant that "not a Nazi" was the lie, and "not Jewish" was the truth. You don't want to push your lies too far.

Comment: He says he and his wife have a shop in London and they left Germany in 1933. Jews and a few other categories of people started leaving that year -- being a shopkeeper implies he was not a commie, for example. I think he was trying to strongly imply (without saying explicitly, Hey, I'm a Jew, just like u guys -- people never say that) his background. The truth in his lie was the similarity of Christopher to his own name, and I agree with your concept. He may have felt he would even falter choosing some very Jewish name unrelated to his real name. He was plainly uncomfortable in that place.

Comment: I don't know. At 1:42 someone says "I know you," and Szell identifies himself as Christopher Hess. The name Christopher must never have been a common one among Jews. But then Szell notices the number tattooed on the wrist of the "I know you" man, showing that he's a Holocaust survivor, and perhaps only then thinks of pretending to be a survivor too. He mentions Golders Green, which was a Jewish area of London when I was there around 1990, and a convenient year. Perhaps the alias was a careless choice that he immediately regretted. The scene is not totally clear on the point.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Hess is neither Jewish nor non-Jewish. It's a place name.
There are literally no clues in the name, other than it's German. The audience may wonder that he chose a 'famous Nazi' last name, but the name in and of itself has no specific association.
Many Jewish family names had been Germanicised before WWII, as many were then Anglicised during & afterwards.* As can happen to any immigrant family, over generations or rapidly, depending on circumstance. There is many a tale, however apocryphal, of immigrants at Ellis Island simply being 'assigned something pronounceable'.

The name Christopher is perhaps harder to reconcile in the same way, though it does have a Hebrew equivalent, כריסטופר. You could perhaps argue it could have been chosen as a popular local name as part of the Anglicisation.

He references Golder's Green in London, which is, for want of a better description, a high-density Jewish area. Certainly one well-known as such.
So having a non-specific Germanic name & hailing from Germany via Golder's Green, I think is as close as you're going to get to claiming without actually saying so, that he is Jewish.

I don't think he's doing anything other than avoiding the direct "Yes, I'm Jewish too." which would be an odd declaration in such circumstances.
He hints he is, by association.

*A friend of mine's family had the last name Pelzmacher [which translates to Furrier (fur maker/dealer) in English] until they escaped to the UK, which they then changed to Fisher. [They now find it amusing that Fisher is almost universally seen as being a Jewish name in the UK - maybe they had to pick from a list, we may never know, the ones who made the change are sadly long departed ;)

Comment: Considering the stakes and how sensitive the Jews he meets would be to the name he provides, you would think he would want to use a name other than Christopher -- it is about as explicitly non-Jewish a first name as one could find; only Jesus (the Spanish name) would be more Christian.  I would bet roughly zero practicing Jews name their kid Christopher or some variant. So I am wondering again if Szell's antisemitism plays a role -- he simply could not bring himself to use a Jewish name. Hess btw is indeed a region but I can think of no famous Jew with that surname.

Comment: See, the trouble with "betting roughly zero…" is that it's very easy to prove that to be a lost bet. It doesn't say anything else, but of course there are a small number of Jewish men called Cristopher, even Christian - https://jewishchronicle.timesofisrael.com/when-christian-is-jewish-living-a-jewish-life-with-a-non-jewish-name/

Comment: The same happens when you challenge that "no famous Jews were called Hess - https://www.germanexpressionismleicester.org/leicesters-collection/the-origins-of-leicesters-expressionist-collection/the-story-of-the-hess-family/ or https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7649-hess-moses-moritz Just because you can't think of one doesn't mean it cannot have ever happened.

Comment: You are really fighting against the obvious point which is, even if these rare examples exist, why use an admittedly unusual name for a Jew if you are pretending to be one? But the fact that Szell's real name is "Christian" explains I think why he chose "Christopher" as his alias.

Comment: I'm only fighting your insistence on your preconception. I have no further interest in this argument. Answer gone.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Szell was such a prominent figure in a government that sought to extinguish an entire heritage, I think it's safe to say that he's anti-Semitic.  However, he also takes note as he's walking through the area that the Diamond District tends to be highly populated by Jewish store owners.  When confronted by an obvious war camp survivor (he notices the numeric tattoo), he decides to angle towards being a friend of Jewish people, rather than a foe.  By stating he's from Golders Green, a predominantly Jewish area of London, it neither confirms nor denies either a Jewish or German heritage, only that his Christopher Hess persona doesn't hate Jews.  By stating he left Germany in '33, he's confirming that he disagreed with Nazi Germany's mindset.  Hitler was appointed Chancellor of Germany in January, 1933.